# How to get parameters from a URL that opened my app on Android

Tags: java, android, url, deep-linking

I need to get some parameters that are coming from an external campaign, where when a user clicks on an external banner on browser my app needs to open,
currently it is happening as expected, my app is opening perfectly... but I need to get all the parameters that came with it.

My XML manifest ->

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="external"
                android:host="deeplink"
                />
        </intent-filter>
```

URL I'm accessing when I click on the banner -> `external://deeplink/?utm_source=abc&utm_medium=abc&utm_campaign=abc`

code that I'm using in the deeplink receiver class ->

```
Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    Log.d("taguison", "URI --->" + appLinkData);
    Log.d("taguison", "utm_source--->" + appLinkData.getQueryParameter("utm_source"));
    Log.d("taguison", "utm_media --->" + appLinkData.getQueryParameter("utm_media"));
    Log.d("taguison", "utm_campaign --->" + appLinkData.getQueryParameter("utm_campaign"));
```

return ->[logcat return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k7hl.png)

what do i need to do to be able to access the remaining parameters that gave null
utm_media and utm_campaign ?

Comment: I already did some tests changing & by %26 in the URL and it worked, I managed to get all the parameters,
however I'm working on a situation where I can't change the URL that comes from outside.